# Can ping another compurer by IP but can can't folder/file sharing in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, networking, lan, file-sharing

I have some computer with same workgroup and one of them is a print sharing server (localPrintServer machine).

All computer can connect into localPrintServer by `\\localPrintServer` or `\\192.168.1.2` (its IP) except one Windows 7 machine. This machine can ping `192.168.1.2` fine but can't access `\\localPrintServer`.

It’s really weird. I checked:

- **Firewall:** Off
- **Computer Browser/Workstation service:** On

Even turn off Window Essential Security, it still can’t access `\\localPrintServer` either.

Answer (score 1):

The problem you are facing that you are unable to connect the printer even-though you are able to ping the printer ip.

We request you to do the following steps

(i) Go to the services.msc and then restart the service name server.

This server is important in the process of mapping drive so restart the server once and then check whether you are able to connect it.

Answer (score 1):

After a day, I found that the computer can't browse `//localPrintServer` was lost Client for Microsoft Network.

[image]

I fixed that by click to Install  and choose Client.

Answer (score 0):

Just went into Contrl Panel> Network & Sharing Center> Change Advance Sharing Settings> Clicked down pointing arrow (for the currently connected network type, e.g. Home or Work)> Turned Off Password Protected Sharing.

I know that this shouldn't have happened (isn't correct way). Because, Password protection is very important for networks. But there might be something and, for the time being, I'm able to browse my Local area network, not only just able to ping them or use internet.